# Karaf: how to repeat previous command

Tags: java, apache-karaf, karaf

How can I repeat previous command in apache karaf? I tried up and down arrows but I don't get previous commands.

Comment: @donwvoter - Please, give explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read manual of the Apache Karaf, default arrows can be used to navigate in command history;

> Key binding
>
> Like on most Unix environment, Karaf console supports some key
>   bindings:
>
> the arrows key to navigate in the commands history

https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/#_key_binding

Also, you can print history with this command

> shell:history prints the commands history

Comment: Just a small remark: in UNIX environment, in order to find the last command you don't need to use the arrow key, but you need to type "Ctrl+P" ("P" stands for "Previous"), the arrow key comes from a special configuration.